# Why use stderr when printf works fine?

Tags: c, stderr

Why should we use stderr when printing a custom error message from printf works fine?

For example why use stderr at all when I can just write a statement like this:

```
    printf("error! you didn't... blah blah blah");
```

Comment: Because it's called `standard error` for a reason (to be used to immediately display **error** messages)?

Comment: Not to mention you would not get that error in your example until something else prints a '\n' or _after_ the program terminates, because stdout is buffered while stderr is not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is good practice to redirect all error messages to `stderr`, while directing regular output to `stdout`.  It is beneficial to do this because anything written to `stderr` is not buffered, i.e., it is immediately written to the screen so that the user can be warned immediately.

Answer (score 22):

`stderr` stands for standard error stream.

In console programming, it is the console -- the screen. It is essentially the same as `stdout`.

The general practice is to redirect all error messages to `stderr` and all regular output to `stdout`.

The reason is that it is possible to redirect standard output to a file instead of the screen. So If you perform a `dir > dirlist.txt` command on the command prompt, the directory listing goes into the text file instead of the screen. If you code to redirect error messages to `stderr`, the errors will always go to the screen instead of the file so that the user could be warned immediately instead of ending up seeing unexpected results in the file.

Using `printf()` will display the error message to the console, which will be stored in the `stdout` buffer, but using `stderr`, is different.

`stderr` can be used as an argument for any function that takes an argument of type `FILE*` expecting an output stream, like `fputs` or `fprintf`.

Although in many cases, both `stdout` and `stderr` are associated with the same output device (like the console), applications may differentiate between what is sent to `stdout` vs `stderr` for situations when one of them is redirected. For example, it is a common practice to redirect the regular output of a console program (`stdout`) to a file, while expecting the error messages to keep appearing in the console.

It is also possible to redirect stderr to another destination from within a program using the `freopen` function.

Also, `stderr` is never fully buffered on startup. It is library-dependent whether the stream is line-buffered or not-buffered by default (see `setvbuf`).

Comment: stdout can also be used as an argument of type FILE*. Great answer though.

Comment: When using shell pipelines writing errors to stdout would cause pipelines like this to do wonky things:

`some_command | cut -f1 -d: | sort -u`

Writing errors to stderr ensures that they still appear on the screen but don't mess up the pipeline.

Comment: good point @MarkE.Hamilton

Answer (score 9):

It is a good practice.

Lets say you use linux. If so, you can run your program following way:

> ./program >out 2>errout

'out' file will contain only STDOUT.
'errout' file will contain only STDERR

So if your output is hundreds of lines long, it is easier to look for few errors in 'errout' rather than look through tons of non-error lines combined with error lines.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Question is, do applications normally do this; such as java, javac, g++, gcc, ar, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `stderr` not being buffered, it is also nice to split output into errors vs. normal output to allow other programs to use of your program more easily. That way, the calling program can redirect standard or error output selectively depending on what it needs to know. This same facility can be used manually through Unix shells - here's one way I use that sometimes:

```
% find / -iname hello.txt
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.MobileBackups: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
^C
% find / -iname hello.txt 2>/dev/null <-- filter "Permission denied" errors
```

Comment: If I just used >, or if I used 1>, it would redirect `stdout` to the specified file. In this case, file descriptor 2 (`stderr`) is being redirected to the file /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect your program's output into a file you still would want to see the errors on screen.