# segmentation fault while debugging the code it compiles okay but debugging it shows segmentation problem

Tags: c, cs50

[segmentation problem occur while debugging the code how can i resolve the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TEFb.png)

debugging problem can't find a solution please help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

 int main(int argc,string argv[])
 {

    int len = strlen(argv[1]);

    if(argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage:./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }


 }
```

Comment: Look at your code and ask yourself when is the proper time to check `argc`, which dictates the valid index range of `argv` : Is it before, or after, you use `argv` in that `strlen` call ? Maybe refer to your C reference and/or [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898021/regarding-mainint-argc-char-argv).

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 2):

**Check if argv is valid before accessing it:**

```
int len = strlen(argv[1]);

    if(argc != 2 )
```

If `argc != 2` evaluates to `true`, then `argv[1]` would be a `NULL` pointer (assuming `argc` is 1).

Check if the arguments are valid before you try to access them, else your program could dereference a `NULL` pointer and exhibit undefined behaviour.

```
if (argc != 2) {
   /* print usage message here.. */
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**strlen() returns a size_t:**

Note that `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. Do not mismatch numeric types.

**Error messages should go to stderr:**

Error messages deserve to be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage:./substitution\n
```

Or as formatted output is not required here, simply:

```
fputs ("Usage:./substitution\n", stderr);
```

See also: [Why use stderr when printf works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19870331/20017547)